# Wifi reseted name and password, how to know what is the password?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

my wifi reseted to a name like "TP-LINK_B06E2E" and password is changed too, how can I know what is the password by default may be? I dont have any cable to connect directly

Comment: It is on your device, look at it! https://hackaday.com/2016/01/27/tp-links-wifi-defaults-to-worst-unique-passwords-ever/

Comment: Usually there will be a card or sticker on the device showing the default password.

Comment: Some routers—particularly those that may have come from your Internet service provider—ship with unique passwords. These passwords are sometimes printed on a sticker on the router itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the router has been reset, then almost all TP-Link routers have `admin`
as default for the Username and Password.
Otherwise, the password might perhaps be in a sticker on the router.

If that does not work for you, then reset the router, which is sometimes done
by inserting a pin into a pin-hole, to return to these defaults.

In any case, I recommend a reset if your router is in a weird state.
You will need to re-enter all your settings.

If you wish more information, please let us know your router model.